# Narrowing Conversion from int to char inside { } | An issue with signedness of char

Tags: c++, vector, char, int, list-initialization

See the behaviour of `char` in case of a `vector<char>` and a standalone `char`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> someInts = {2, 3, 1 + 5};
    // I can perform operations   ^^^^^   inside the braces in this case

    // vector<char> someChars = {'a', 'b', 'r' + 'z'};
    // But doing the same in case of char  ^^^^^^^^^  gives an error

    // However, it works for a standalone char
    char ch = 'r' + 'z';
    cout << ch;
    // Value^^^is '∞' as expected
}
```

Uncommenting the `vector<char>` line gives:

> Error: **narrowing conversion of '236' from 'int' to 'char' inside { }**

This was the problem.

---

Then I read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) documentation of **List Initialization**, and saw the following which might be related to this problem:

> ## Narrowing conversions
>
> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by
>   prohibiting the following:
>
> - *many other reasons*
> - **conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type    that cannot represent all values of the original, except where
>     source    is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly
>     in the    target type**

It made me understand the error message (I guess), and I changed `vector<char>` to `vector<unsigned char>` and it worked:

```
vector<unsigned char> someChars = {'a', 'b', 'r' + 'z'};
for (char ch : someChars)
    cout << '_' << ch;
```

> Output: `_a_b_∞`

---

So, my question is:

1. If *signedness* of `char` was the problem, how did the standalone version of `char` work in that case? With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default) thread on stackoverflow, **how did the same compiler choose `signed char` for `vector<char>` and `unsigned char` for `char`?**
2. If my deduction of the problem is wrong, what is the correct reason behind this issue?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213289/discussion-on-question-by-ardent-coder-narrowing-conversion-from-int-to-char-ins).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1+5` is an `int` so there is no problem using it to initialize a `vector<int>` entry.

`'r' + 's'` is an `int` (236) which is out of range of `char` on your system. So there **is** a problem trying to use it to initialize a `vector<char>` entry. This is exactly the sort of case that the rule about list initialization disallowing narrowing conversions  was designed for.

You would get the same error for `vector<char> x = { 'a', 'b', 123456 };`

Standalone `char` either has the same properties as `signed char` or `unsigned char`, which one it is is implementation-defined and some compilers have a switch to choose (e.g. `-funsigned-char` on GCC). To be clear, it is still a distinct type in either case.

---

*In your words,* `char` was indeed signed in both the cases as Nathan Oliver explained in the comments. The problem is that you have a wrong notion that the standalone `char` was unsigned in your case. Just because `char ch = 'r' + 'z';` compiled doesn't show that it is unsigned. You probably thought that it was unsigned because `'r' + 'z' == 236` which doesn't fit into a `signed char`. No, it does fit into a `signed char` for the following reason:

`char ch = 'r' + 'z';` is an **out-of-range conversion**. Since C++20 the result will be `-20` (assuming plain char is 8-bit signed as indicated by your earlier error message, and the system uses ASCII encoding) , prior to that the result was implementation-defined.

---

So, don't assume things. If you are confused whether char is signed or unsigned on your system, simply check `CHAR_MIN`.

Comment: replace `which is out of range of char` with `which is out of range of for char on your system`?

Comment: `'r' + 's'` is `236`. It could be out of `char`'s range as you said, but only if it was `signed char`. Then `vector<char>` should also have been `vector<signed char>`. But in my case `vector<char>` was indeed `vector<signed char>` but the *r + s* `char` was `unsigned char`.

Comment: @ArdentCoder `char` and `signed char` are different types, but have the same properties on your system

Comment: I'm not talking about `123456` which is clearly out of range. I was dealing with `236` in my code which is well within the range of `unsigned char`. But as you said it's compiler-dependent, my compiler saw it like `signed char` and I agree. Then why did the other `char` in my code was not seen like signed, because it compiled and displayed the infinity symbol as expected.

Comment: @ArdentCoder -- in case it isn't clear: the signedness of `char` is determined by the compiler and the compiler uses the **same** signedness throughout the compilation. It does not make case-by-case decisions while compiling a single source file. Some compilers give you a command-line switch that lets you choose which one to use, but, again, that applies throughout the compilation.

Comment: Oh yes, I couldn't digest the *out of range conversion* discussion in the comments because my power went off and I was testing your explanations in an online compiler from a mobile device which didn't display `∞` lol